# How to properly do a OR condition in cypher neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm doing a dating website for fun with neo4j and am strugling with the match query

```
WITH  COLLECT(DISTINCT other) as to_exclude
MATCH (other:user) WHERE 'man' IN other.interest AND NOT other.email = 'some.email@gmail.com' AND other:man OR other:woman AND 'man' IN other.interest AND NOT other.email  = 'some.email@gmail.com'
WITH to_exclude, COLLECT(DISTINCT other) AS result  
WITH [elem IN result WHERE NOT elem IN to_exclude | elem] AS final_result
UNWIND final_result AS to_return
RETURN to_return
```

But That's an horrible query because OR force me to repeat myself

At beginning I was doing something like `WHERE other:man OR other:woman AND ...` but it's appear that the first part of the OR group was not subject to my other condition.

so I had to to repeat myself
`condition1 AND condition2 OR condition3 AND contidion1`

I'd like something more practical and easy to read

Comment: Could you please share what is expected from the query?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us your intent by grouping your logical operations with parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) for `AND` and `OR` does not seem to be documented for Cypher. However, using [this nice test](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65127/how-to-test-for-logic-operator-precedence) we can tell that `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

Thus, this clause from your query (reformatted to show interesting patterns):

```
WHERE
  'man' IN other.interest AND NOT other.email = 'some.email@gmail.com'
  AND
  other:man

    OR

  other:woman
  AND
  'man' IN other.interest AND NOT other.email = 'some.email@gmail.com'
```

can be simplified to this equivalent clause:

```
WHERE
  (other:man OR other:woman) AND 'man' IN other.interest AND NOT other.email = 'some.email@gmail.com'
```

Comment: I know there is not really documentation about it. I only post this question to let people be aware of it. Because it should be more documented. Stack Overflow is much more practical than how I found it in the first place. ( going on  official neo4j slack and feeling idiotic for asking such question )